# Build Command in build setting in Eclipse C/C++

Tags: eclipse, string, list, makefile

In CDT eclipse, I have a project with my own makefile.
So in the properties of the project, I add a configuration. I would like to use C/C++ build-> Build variable to give to my makefile some variable.

For example in Build Variable, I declare:

```
NAME   TYPE           VALUE
_FOO   String         X232
_PLOP  String List    BLUE || RED
```

After that, I write in C/C++ Build-> Build Command::

```
make -f pathOfMyMakefile FOO={_FOO} PLOP={_PLOP}
```

The make command is: `make -f pathOfMyMakefile FOO=X232 PLOP=BLUE RED`

The makefile doesn't understand RED(It's normal..). I would like a list of variable .
Do you know if is it possible to give a string list to makefile.
I would like add some variable in this list.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As Make itself is concerned, setting a multi-word value is done in the same manner as a single-word value.

As a matter of fact, they are in the exact same category of variables, no matter if the value contains a space (2 words or more), or none (one word).

You can set values to Make variables, in one of the following three:

```
1. Environment
2. Makefile
3. Command-line
```

In your example, the values are set by the command-line, as long as the variable and its value are in **one** argument, all of the value, **including** any spaces *within* the value, will be set as the value of the variable.

Usually, in a UNIX-shell, this is done by some sort of quoting.

For example, given a makefile, like:

```
all::
    : $(foo)
```

Here we run Make, with different command-line assignment to `foo`:

```
# one-word value

$ make foo=a
: a


# multi-word value

$ make foo='a b'
: a b


# multi-word value

$ make foo="a b"
: a b


# multi-word value

$ make foo=a\ b
: a b
```

As you can see, they are all the same.

As the shell removes any quoting, and what get passed - to Make - as a **single** argument is: "foo= a b", which Make will parse as a **single** assignment, i.e.: *foo* as the variable name, and *a b* as its value.

**But**, compare the following:

```
# try a multi-word assignment in the command-line, without quoting

$ make foo=a b
make: *** No rule to make target 'b'.  Stop.
```

This is, because a Unix-shell, will force a new argument after the white-space, so that Make will see the following arguments:

```
Argumnet 0: make
Argumnet 1: foo=a
Argumnet 2: b
```

Now, argument 1 is a variable assignment, with one-word value.
The 2nd argumnet *b*, is not a variable assignment, as it doesn't contain an equal ('=') sign, and therefore treated as non-option argumnet (i.e. an argument without a '-' or '--' prefix), and therefore is taken to be as an explicit 'default goal', overriding the implicit 'all' target in our makefile.

Comment: Ok, I understand the problem. If I write ' "foo= a b " ', Make understands $(foo). If I want parse $(foo) to find _a_ and _b_,  must I  use some UNIX command like cut, or awk?